# Weird -- Text on web page is bolded after asp.net authentication

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, authentication, bold

I have no idea what is causing this, but after I log in (using asp.net authentication), all my text is on the page is bolded. (Before I log in, the text is normal).

I'm working on an ASP.Net MVC2 application

I don't think this is a CSS issue, because when I look at the HTML, something is adding extra   tags everywhere... and it only happens after logging in.

I'm not even sure what source code to provide... so I'm hoping someone might have an idea why these extra tags are being inserted into the page.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the html of the page after user is authenticated? Looks like a missing </b> tag.

Comment: +1 for unclosed tag, likely in the user welcome panel.

Comment: yup, that's it. I'm glad it was such a simple (but stupid) thing. Thanks!

Comment: @Cybernate: Would you add an answer to allow @Ray close the question, please?

Comment: @Alex: Posted my comment as answer.

Answer (score 1):

From my comment above:

Can you post the html of the page after user is authenticated?

**Looks like a missing `</b>` tag.**